# API call not calling or attempting to call in Swift app

Tags: json, swift, debugging

In my Swift code below it should print a random word in the debug section. Right now the word inside is not being printed so the code is not being called. I don't know what to do at this point.

```
var randomWord: String?

func fetchRandomWord() {
     WordAPI.fetchRandomWords { [weak self] result in
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             if let randomWord = result?.first { // Get the first random word
                 print("IINside")
                 self?.randomWord = randomWord
               
                 print("Fetched random word:", randomWord) // Print the random word
             } else {
          print("wrestling")
             }
         }
     }
 }

    
truct WordAPI {
    static let baseURL = URL(string: "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word")!
    
    static func fetchRandomWords(completion: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
        let endpoint = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("random-words")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                completion(words)
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least print all possible errors. As of now you ignore all errors. Add `print(error)` inside the `guard`. Add `print(error)` inside the `catch`. Use the debugger. Step through the code line by line and see what is actually happening. No guessing needed.

Comment: your URL `https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word/random-words` is **wrong**. Put that into your browser and you will see what you get, `Error 404: Not Found`. Try just the `baseURL`, without the `appendingPathComponent(...)`. See the docs here: https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/home

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word does return a word. What you put is words that does not work and causes a error. Still having problems

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `What you put is words that does not work and causes a error.` There is nothing in the docs that takes a word and return something. As I said, and as you say, the baseURL returns a random word. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Its not return anything which is not a error your correct. Its not even going through the do statements its going right to catch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my test code (in SwiftUI, sorry that's all I have). The example code can be reworked for non-SwiftUI systems.

The example code shows how to "connect" to the API and return an array of 10 random words,
as a demontration of the approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var randomWords: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        if randomWords.isEmpty { ProgressView() }
        List(randomWords, id: \.self) { word in
            Text(word)
        }
        .onAppear {
            WordAPI.fetchRandomWords(10) { results in
                if let rndWords = results {
                    randomWords = rndWords
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct WordAPI {
    static let baseURL = "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word"
    
    static func fetchRandomWords(_ n: Int, completion: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
        if let endpoint = URL(string: baseURL + "?number=\(n)") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpoint) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
                    completion(words)
                } catch {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```